# Reaading Audio in a UWP application

Tags: audio, uwp, windows-10-universal

Hi everyone I'm trying to read an audio file in a UWP application using the method shown below:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(); 

StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + fileName));
Debug.WriteLine(file.Path);
var f = File.Exists(file.Path);

player.AutoPlay = false;
player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
player.Play();
```

But I get the following esception: `System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Focus.Services.Utility' threw an exception.'` 
Please can someone help ? I tried several methods for reading audio files but none seems to give.

Comment: Can't you just properly format your code? If you want people to read your question, make it easy for them.

Comment: I have tested your code, it works in my side.  From exception info, the problem is `Focus.Services.Utility` has not been initialized. Could your show more detail about  'Focus.Services.Utility' ?